# Is there any way to exit for each loop immediately once condition gets true?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i need to exit for each loop immediately once condition gets true. and want to return current index where loop breaks. below is my sample xml and xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:element name="Data">
            <xsl:call-template name="TempData" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="TempData">
        <xsl:element name="TempData">
            <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Subject/SubTest">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@System='OK' and @SubFlag!='1'">
                            <xsl:attribute name="CurrentSubFlag">
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="TempData/*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<Data>
    <Subject>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="csdcd" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="zxczx" System="OK"> </SubTest>  
    </Subject>
    <TempData CurrentSubFlag="abc"/>
</Data>
```

output xml should be

```
<Data>
    <Subject>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="csdcd" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="zxczx" System="OK"> </SubTest>  
    </Subject>
    <TempData CurrentSubFlag="2"/>
</Data>
```

if input is

```
<Data>
    <Subject>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>  
    </Subject>
    <TempData CurrentSubFlag="abc"/>
</Data>
```

then output will be same CurrentSubFlag="abc"

Comment: `xsl:for-each`is not a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xsl:for-each` is not a loop, and the result you need can be accomplished without a loop or recursion.

Given:

**XML**

```
<Data>
    <Subject>
        <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="csdcd" System="OK"> </SubTest>
        <SubTest SubFlag="zxczx" System="OK"> </SubTest>  
    </Subject>
    <TempData CurrentSubFlag="abc"/>
</Data>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TempData">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="count(/Data/Subject/SubTest[not(@SubFlag=1 and @System='OK')][1]/preceding-sibling::SubTest) + 1" />
    <TempData CurrentSubFlag="{$index}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Subject>
    <SubTest SubFlag="1" System="OK"/>
    <SubTest SubFlag="csdcd" System="OK"/>
    <SubTest SubFlag="zxczx" System="OK"/>
  </Subject>
  <TempData CurrentSubFlag="2"/>
</Data>
```

---

### Added:

To accommodate your added condition, try:

```
<xsl:template match="TempData">
    <xsl:variable name="fail" select="/Data/Subject/SubTest[not(@SubFlag=1 and @System='OK')]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$fail">
            <TempData CurrentSubFlag="{count($fail[1]/preceding-sibling::SubTest) + 1}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks michael it works
only if all SubFlag are = 1 then CurrentSubFlag we be same like "abc".
could you please re-modify xslt

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is equivalent to a while loop. This can be done with a recursive template having a variable (see [How to do a "while"-like loop in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127693/how-to-do-a-while-like-loop-in-xslt) or http://www.humbug.in/2010/a-sample-loop-in-xsl-alternative-for-while-for-loops-2/ ).

In pseudocode:

```
function findFirst(elements)
    foreach element in elements
        if test(element)
            return element
```

Is the same as:

```
function findFirst(elements, offset)
    element = elements[offset]
    if test(element)
        return element
    else
        return findFirst(elements, offset + 1)
```

the latter can be done with recursive templates (see the links)

(Note: the code assumes that the element exists)

Comment: how i can use /Data/Subject/SubTest nodeset with recursive templates

Comment: How about using [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) ? I've edited the code to make it more clear. You need a variable for the counter index, and might succeed by comparing it with position().

Comment: i already used could u please provide sample code snippet for this xslt

Comment: Please try implementing it yourself, and tell if it doesn't work. Update the question with the new code, and we'll go from there, I can provide more tips.